# radio buttons keep switching

Tags: laravel, radio-button, laravel-livewire

I have three radio buttons but they not work properly. when I click one, the other one blink and then all of them seem unchecked. livewire model changes correctly but buttons mess it up.

```php
  <div class="mt-4">
            <label  class="block mb-6">
                <input type="radio" name="package" class="custom-radio mr-2" wire:model="package" value="x" />
                x
            </label>      
            <label  class="block mb-6">
                <input type="radio" name="package" class="custom-radio mr-2" wire:model="package" value="y" />
                y
            </label>      
            <label  class="block mb-6">
                <input type="radio" name="package" class="custom-radio mr-2" wire:model="package" value="z" />
                z
            </label>      
        </div>
```

Comment: What type of property is `$package` in your Livewire component? Is it `public` and a `string`?

Comment: @Yinci yes public string

Comment: You don't need the `name` attribute when using Livewire. HTML has specific behaviour for radio buttons, it might conflict with Livewire. Does removing that attribute help?

Comment: nope, I'll test it in live maybe it's about my local

Comment: Is there a `wire:ignore` anywhere? As soon as you have a `wire:model` on a radio, Livewire will handle checking the correct radio button based on the value of the linked property, so it's very peculiar that you are having issues.

Comment: no wire:ignore in code. problem still displays in live so I use input radio button hidden and create a custom div looks like radio button. It works

Answer (score 0):

You have to give diffrent Id's to all radio buttons. Now all radio buttons having No ID, so it is not selecting proper one

Try below :

```
<div class="mt-4">
    <label  class="block mb-6" for="rd_x">
        <input type="radio" name="package" class="custom-radio mr-2" wire:model="package" value="x" id="rd_x" />
        x
    </label>
    <label  class="block mb-6" for="rd_y">
        <input type="radio" name="package" class="custom-radio mr-2" wire:model="package" value="y" id="rd_y"  />
        y
    </label>
    <label  class="block mb-6" for="rd_z">
        <input type="radio" name="package" class="custom-radio mr-2" wire:model="package" value="z" id="rd_z"  />
        z
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not working even I give ids

Comment: Updated code, pls check, add for in label

Answer (score -1):

You can archieve the desired behavior by using the following code, `checked` attribute should be used

```
<div class="mt-4">
  <label class="block mb-6">
    <input type="radio" name="package" class="custom-radio mr-2" wire:model="package" value="x" checked="{{ $package === 'x' ? 'checked' : '' }}" />
    x
  </label>      
  <label class="block mb-6">
    <input type="radio" name="package" class="custom-radio mr-2" wire:model="package" value="y" checked="{{ $package === 'y' ? 'checked' : '' }}" />
    y
  </label>      
  <label class="block mb-6">
    <input type="radio" name="package" class="custom-radio mr-2" wire:model="package" value="z" checked="{{ $package === 'z' ? 'checked' : '' }}" />
    z
  </label>      
</div>
```

Comment: but this solution not prevent switching and blinking on focus

Comment: what do you mean by prevent switching and blinking?